# Removing UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitextfield

I'm having some trouble dynamically removing UITextFields from my scrollview when the user taps a button. The UITextields were created programatically. This is what I have thus far, any help would be appreciated.

```
-(IBAction)resetAll{

int textFieldTag;

for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
    textFieldTag = i + 100;
    UITextField *myTextField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:textFieldTag]; 
    [myTextField removeFromSuperview];
    [myTextField release];
}
}
```

Comment: What is your trouble, exactly? You didn't describe what happened.

Comment: Do you want to remove specific UITextFields or every UITextField? -- Some more information would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)resetAll
{    
    NSMutableArray *arrayTextFields=[yourScrollView subViews]; //get all subviews from your scrollview

for (int i=0; i<[arrayTextFields count]; i++) 
{
    if([[arrayTextFields objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) //check for UITextField
    {
        UITextField *textField=(UITextField *)[arrayTextFields objectAtIndex:i];
        [textField removeFromSuperView]; //Remove textField
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement this....

```
-(IBAction)resetAll
 {
     for (UITextField *myTextField in [myScrollView subviews]) 
          [myTextField removeFromSuperview];
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
-(IBAction)resetAll
 {
  for (UITextField *tf in myScrollView) {
  [tf removeFromSuperview];
  [tf release];
 }

}
```